# Should I play Borderlands The Presequel or Tales from the Borderlands first?

Tags: borderlands-series

I'm currently about to play both games (are bought and installed). Played BL 1 and 2. Do either one have spoilers about the other (so I could play the unspoiled one first)

Comment: It's difficult to judge what spoilers Tales may contain or what from the presequel may spoil it, as only 2/5ths of it have been released yet. Speculatively, a reasonable person would expect a large number of the people playing Tales to have played the other Borderlands games that came out before it so the path of least spoiler-ness should be the order of publication.

Comment: I guess I could rephrase it as 'Which one comes first in the timeline' I guess you can't spoil something that hasn't happened yet, even if I guess you could foreshadow stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borderlands: The Presequel is between Borderlands 2 (the sequel) and Borderlands 1.

And here's a quote from [Tales from the Borderlands FAQ:](https://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/53341/tales-from-the-borderlands-unofficial-faq-read-before-posting)

> **(5) When and where in the Borderlands timeline is this game set?**
>   During the Tales from the Borderlands SXSW panel, it was mentioned
>   that the game takes place in Pandora after Borderlands 2 and its DLC.

Comment: @Fredy31 Well, I'd actually play Borderlands 2 before the Presequel. It might be before part 2 in the timeline, but it came out after BL2 and you will understand more of it after playing Borderlands 2.